# Reverse SSH tunnel with JSCH Java

Tags: java, ssh, reverse, jsch, ssh-tunnel

Is it possible to do a reverse ssh connection using JSCH? If it is not, is there any other pure Java library that I can use to do a reverse tunnel SSH connection?

The command I want to mimic is similar than:

`ssh -fN -R 7000:localhost:22 username@yourMachine-ipaddress`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an example gist that shows how to do it here:
https://gist.github.com/ymnk/2318108#file-portforwardingr-java

The method you want to look at is session.setPortForwardingR()

```
session.setPortForwardingR(rport, lhost, lport);
```